# int* vector accepts only the first given value

Tags: c, vector, struct

I'm experiencing some troubles with my code written in C. It's all about an int * vector intially declared and dynamically allocated but when it comes to filling it with data it stuck on the first element and won't increment the counter to fill the rest of the vector

my header file : instance.h

```
struct pbCoupe
{
   int tailleBarre; 
   int nbTaillesDem; 
   int nbTotPcs;
   int * taille; 
int * nbDem; 
};
```

my code : coupe.c

```
pb->taille = (int*) malloc (pb->nbTaillesDem * sizeof(int)); 
pb->nbDem = (int*) malloc (pb->nbTaillesDem * sizeof(int));


while (i < pb->nbTaillesDem)
{
    fscanf_s(instanceFile,"%s",data,sizeof(data)); 
    pb->taille[i] = atoi(data); //<-- here is the problem !! it only accept the first value and ignore all the rest 

    printf("%s\n",data);

    fscanf_s(instanceFile,"%s",data,sizeof(data)); 
    pb->nbDem[i] = atoi(data); //<-- the same problem here too !!
    printf("%s\n",data);

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Please give all inputs and outputs, especially add the missing variable types, and tell what you wanted to happen instead.

Comment: Please show the data in "instanceFile". The problem may be reading string from instanceFile using fscanf_s.

Comment: pb->nbTaillesDem is the number of elements in the text file ! I'm going to read line by line a coupe of pb->taille and pb->nbDem
This code is supposed to give me 2 vectors filled with int

Comment: 6500 //pb->tailleBarre
8 //pb->nbTaillesDem
52 //pb->nbTotPcs
350 6 //pb->taille & pb->nbDem
520 7 //the same for the rest until the end
1230 5
500 7
630 10
4200 4
2500 9
660 4

Comment: but there is no problem when reading from the file because every time I print "data" and it's okay !

Answer (score -1):

Your interpretation of `sizeof` is wrong, since `data` is the buffer that the string is being parsed into.

It returns the size of the the variable, not the size of the the what the variable (or namely a pointer) points to

Strings in C are all pointer to the size would be 4 bytes on a 32-bit system, 8 on a 64-bit.

Since it prints all the number it reading more numbers that intended with each loop iteration 4 bytes = 4 characters, atoi on parses the first integer and returns,

EDIT: If it is a buffer array, `sizeof` returns the size of the array.

You need to make sure you are only reading in a single number per iteration of the loop to solve this issue.

If you don't care for the literal string, best thing you can do is use:

```
fscanf(instanceFile, "%d", ((pb->taille) + i)));
//and store the integer into the index right away
//last param same as &pb->taille[i]
```

Comment: but we do not know how data was declared... it maybe char data[128]; for example. In which case, sizeof(data) is 128. But, if data is declared like this: char *data;

Comment: char data[10];
this is the declaration of data

Comment: So you are reading 10 bytes (or 10 characters from the file) per iteration, as Brad was saying. You need to limit your read in to the first whitespace/null character after the integer string per iteration

Comment: Yes, or end of string